# how to deserialise an json object into model in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I m trying to deserialize the json response object which contains total count and list of users. Do I need to store totalcount in user model

I have tried using map and pipe but cant figure out to normalize the data in model interfaces

```
"total_count": 5,
"incomplete_results": false,
"items": [
 {
   "login": "mojombo",
   "id": 1,
   "node_id": "MDQ6VXNlcjE=",
   "avatar_url": "https://avatars0.githubusercontent.com/u/1?v=4",
   "gravatar_id": "",
   "url": "https://api.github.com/users/mojombo",
   "html_url": "https://github.com/mojombo",
   "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/mojombo/followers",
   "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/mojombo/following{/other_user}",
   "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/mojombo/gists{/gist_id}",
   "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/mojombo/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
   "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/mojombo/subscriptions",
   "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/mojombo/orgs",
   "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/mojombo/repos",
   "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/mojombo/events{/privacy}",
   "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/mojombo/received_events",
   "type": "User",
   "site_admin": false,
   "score": 97.55435
 },
 {
   "login": "tmcw",
   "id": 32314,
   "node_id": "MDQ6VXNlcjMyMzE0",
   "avatar_url": "https://avatars2.githubusercontent.com/u/32314?v=4",
   "gravatar_id": "",
   "url": "https://api.github.com/users/tmcw",
   "html_url": "https://github.com/tmcw",
   "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/tmcw/followers",
   "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/tmcw/following{/other_user}",
   "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/tmcw/gists{/gist_id}",
   "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/tmcw/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
   "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/tmcw/subscriptions",
   "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/tmcw/orgs",
   "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/tmcw/repos",
   "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/tmcw/events{/privacy}",
   "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/tmcw/received_events",
   "type": "User",
   "site_admin": false,
   "score": 82.624016
 }
export interface User{
  id:string;
  url:string;
  login:string; 
}
```

where and how should I store total count also

Comment: Is this `total count` === `no of objects in the list`? and if you are getting the total_count as separate key value then why don't you use it?

Comment: no the items are less than the total count  as its paginated response

Comment: And do you want only three properties from the JSON?

Comment: yes , I need only few properties like id, login, profile url to be used in component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To cast to a model, try this:

```
const model = Object.create(YourModel.prototype)
Object.assign(model, JSON.parse(jsonString))
```

or

```
 var model = new YourModel();
 model.copyInto(JSON.parse(jsonString));
```

To include count, you can create a new Custom Model:

**CustomModel**

```
{
  yourModel: YourModel;
  count:number;
}
```

and then:

```
const model = Object.create(CustomModel.prototype)
Object.assign(model, JSON.parse(jsonString))
```

Comment: what about total count ? i think we cant include total count of users in user model

Comment: You can create a new custom model for it having properties: `yourModel : YourModel` and `count:number` and then replace `var model = new YourModel();` with `var model = new YourCustomModel();`

Answer (score 1):

I would use a seperate variable to store the total_count.

TS Code:

```
user: User[] = [];
totalCount: any;

constructor() {
    this.user = this.data.items as User[];
    this.totalCount = this.data.total_count;
}
```

[`WORKING_DEMO`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yrstkt)

Comment: I want to filter all the unwanted information of user, In your demo if you print the user object u can see lot of unwanted information , I like to filter it during  service call only

Comment: @tonystark yes, seen after!